# jQuery remove or hide all svg on the canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, svg

I want to remove or hide the svg I double click on.

```
var draw = SVG('output').size(1000, 500);

var table = draw.circle(50)
.fill('#00ff0000')
.stroke('black')]
.center(50, 50);
table.attr("class", "table");

$("svg").on('dblclick',function(event){
           $(".table").hide(); 
        });

var desk = draw.rect(50,50)
.fill('green')
.stroke('black')
.move(100,0);
desk.attr("class", "desk");

$("svg").on('dblclick',function(event){
           $(".desk").hide(); 
        });

var chair = draw.rect(50,50)
.fill('green')
.stroke('black')
.move(200,0);
desk.attr("class", "chair");

$("svg").on('dblclick',function(event){
           $(".chair").hide(); 
        });


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.3/svg.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

I want to hide the one that I double click on, but now the result is that, all of them are hidden if I double click any one of them. Even if I double click the blank space of canvas, all of the SVG images are also hidden.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `$("svg")`, that targets every single svg element on the page.
When this code runs `$("svg").on('dblclick',function(event){ $(".table").hide(); });` for example,
every SVG on the page gets the `"dblclick"` event to hide `".table"`. To solve this, instead of globally selecting all svg elements, use CSS selectors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors to only grab the svg related to the class you give it (e.g. maybe you want `$("svg.table").on('dblclick')` or something like that)